# Methods and Constructors

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, constructor

How do you use a method with code inside in?

```
public void initialiseVariables(){
             name=timestamp.substring(0, 20);

            // numofdep = timestamp.substring(35, 37);
             //noofovertime = timestamp.substring(38, 40);
     if(timestamp.charAt(20)=='C')
         city=true;
     if(timestamp.charAt(21)=='U')
         union=true;
identificationnumber=Integer.parseInt(timestamp.substring(22,26));//to get an integer from a string use the integer.parseint
             numofdep = Integer.parseInt(timestamp.substring(35, 37));
             noofovertime = Integer.parseInt(timestamp.substring(38, 40));
     hoursworked=Integer.parseInt(timestamp.substring(27,29));
              hourlyrate = Double.parseDouble( timestamp.substring(30, 34));
 }
```

I don't understand what you put inside the constructor. Also how do you determine what you put inside the parameters? like this constructor my friend wrote.

```
 Employees(){

     this.timestamp=timestamp;
     initialiseVariables();
 }
```

So how do I use for example the line,

```
 name=timestamp.substring(0, 20);
```

in my main class?

Comment: You really need to take a course or read a book on basic programming if you don't know what a method/function/routine is.

Comment: I'm afraid your question doesn't make much sense. You are unlikely to get very useful answers unless you reword your question to be more clear about what you're asking. e.g. I don't understand what you mean by "a method with code inside" because (almost) all methods have code.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. But if `timestamp` is a member of class `Employee`, you can only refer to it from `main` via an instance of `Employee`. Note that `main` is static, so this holds even if `main` is a method of `Employee`.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

[Recommended reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/)

Class Employees:

```
 private String timestamp;

 Employees(String timestamp){
     this.timestamp=timestamp;
     initialiseVariables();
 }


private void initialiseVariables(){
    String name=timestamp.substring(0, 20);
    ...
}

public void doSomethingWithTimestamp(){...}
```

Class Main:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    Employees e = new Employees();
    e.doSomethingWithTimestamp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your constructor is wrong, you write :

```
Employees(){

     this.timestamp=timestamp;
     initialiseVariables();
 }
```

you have to constructor to following form :

```
Employees([selected your type] timestamp){

     this.timestamp=timestamp;
     initialiseVariables();
 }
```

this constructor has one parameter and set that to own object member(timestamp) and call initial member.
You have to read java core, books such as "Thinking In Java" help you.

please your means completely for better help.

Comment: I suggestion anyone post down vote, comment your reason, because I hope learning new things by this forum.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like you're trying to run before you can walk here. I'd strongly suggest taking a look at the following tutorial vidoes on youtube by theNewBoston.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&v=SHIT5VkNrCg&feature=fvwp

Just spending some time watching these videos will make things MUCH easier for you. I understand what it's like when you have a teacher that throws everything at you without much help. Those videos will help.

Sometimes he gets things a little wrong, but his videos are the best I've found for getting started. Good luck :)